# Post image on user wall with app message followed by app URL

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

In my application, I am posting images on walls, and it works fine, but now my requirement is  to print my app's URL with a message and have it so that when a user clicks on  the link, he is redirected to my app.

Comment: Great! And what do you need from us?

Comment: You can apply message to the image just add message to the array where you use your facebook api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl method, Am using this and it works fine

```
$attachment =  array(
                            'access_token' => "accesstoken",
                            'caption' => "Hey -- this is caption",
                            'description' => "Your Desc",
                            'link' => "http://www.example.com/",
                            'picture'=> "path/image.png"
                        );

                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXX/feed');
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
                        $result = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close ($ch);
```